# SQL Server Transaction successful with wrong Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2014

I have a simple SQL statement to create a table like this:

```
Create table tblAccountBalance
(
    Id int,
    AccountName nvarchar(200),
    Balance int
)

insert into tblAccountBalance values (1, 'Mark', 1000);
insert into tblAccountBalance values (2, 'Mary', 1000);
```

Resulting in

```
Id AccountName Balance
-----------------------
1  Mark        1000
2  Mary        1000
```

Then I create a transaction like this:

```
begin try
    begin transaction   -- must have transaction keyword here!
        update tblAccountBalance 
        set Balance = Balance - 100 
        where Id = 1

        update tblAccountBalance 
        set Balance = Balance + 100 
        where Id = 2

        commit transaction --or simply commit, but by default, it is commit WORK - thus you cannot specify transaction name, best is to put transaction
        print 'Transaction successful!'
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction --or simply rollback, but again, it might be similar to transaction, best is to put transaction keyword
    print 'Transaction is rolled back!'
end catch
```

Which, when executed, simply transfers 100 units of money from Mark to Mary:

```
Id AccountName Balance
-----------------------
1  Mark        900
2  Mary        1100
```

Now, continuing from the above - updated - table, to introduce error in the transaction, I change the transaction to make the second update statement having `nvarchar` as Id like this:

```
begin try
    begin transaction
        update tblAccountBalance 
        set Balance = Balance - 100 
        where Id = 1

        update tblAccountBalance 
        set Balance = Balance + 100 
        where Id = '24'    -- note the Id here is changed

        commit transaction
        print 'Transaction successful!'
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
    print 'Transaction is rolled back!'
end catch
```

To my surprise, executing the above query resulting in:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
(0 row(s) affected)
Transaction successful!

Id  AccountName Balance
-----------------------
1   Mark        800
2   Mary        1100
```

Which is not the desired result.

But then, if I further continue from the undesired updated table result above with a modified transaction (again, in the second update Id) like this:

```
begin try
    begin transaction
        update tblAccountBalance 
        set Balance = Balance - 100 
        where Id = 1

        update tblAccountBalance 
        set Balance = Balance + 100 
        where Id = 'A24'     -- note the Id here is changed

        commit transaction
        print 'Transaction successful!'
end try
begin catch
    rollback transaction
    print 'Transaction is rolled back!'
end catch
```

This results in:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
(0 row(s) affected)
Transaction is rolled back!

Id  AccountName Balance
------------------------
1   Mark        800
2   Mary        1100
```

Which is my desired result. What's wrong with the second transaction? Why does the update still getting executed?

I am using SQL Server 2014 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your second experiment is actually successful and executed. When there is a operation that compare 2 different data types, SQL Server will perform implicit conversion.Refer to [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) for more details. So there is conversion of your `id = '24'` to type int, so it eventually becomes `id = 24`. So the experiment will deduct balance from Mark, and add the balance of record with `id = 24`, but since there is no record with this id, nothing changes.

In your third experiment, the implicit conversion fails (cannot convert `A24` to integer type) and eventually the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Oh my.. I got it wrong because of the implicit conversion. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is identical with others, but you are the first to answer plus having reference to the MSDN data type precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Your second transaction is successful that's why the `UPDATE` was still executed. The `UPDATE` statement that you changed:

```
update tblAccountBalance set Balance = Balance + 100 where Id = '24' --note the Id here is changed
```

did not cause any error. It simply did not return any rows with `Id = '24'`, but without error.

Your third transaction resulted in an error that's why the `UPDATE` is rolled back.

```
update tblAccountBalance set Balance = Balance + 100 where Id = 'A24' --note the Id here is changed
```

The above will result to an error like this:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A24' to data type
>   int.

Since your `Id` is `INT`, SQL Server tries to convert `A24` which is `VARCHAR` to `INT` but fails to do so and thus the error.

Comment: Oh my.. I got it wrong because of the implicit conversion. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your second experiment was successful because `nvarchar` can be implicitly converted to `int`. String `'24'` can be converted to integer value of `24`. See [Implicit Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Oh my.. I got it wrong because of the implicit conversion. Thanks for your explanation.